# What does "inet" stand for in the ip utility?

Tags: networking, terminology

I would assume '**inet**' stands for internet ip address, but is that correct? (And '**inet6**' being internet ip address v.6.)

`ip a` yields a list of virtual (and physical?) network devices. When an IP address is mapped to a device, it is displayed as

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

According to https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/INET, the following definitions are possible:
Acronym Definition

- INET  Internet
- INET  Intranet
- INET  International Networking
- INET  Information Network
- INET  Institute for New Economic Thinking (est. 2009)
- INET  International Networking (conference)
- INET  Institutional Network (Hawaii Department of Education)
- INET  Instruments and Experimental Techniques (journal)
- INET  Interagency Narcotics Enforcement Team
- INET  Instinet LLC
- INET  Integrated Network Enhanced Telemetry
- INET  Instructional Network

Comment: Why would it be any of those other things? Why would it be anything other than _internet_?

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't contradict what I said. I'm just curious as to why you thought it would be anything other than internet-related and why it would be, for example, _"Institutional Network (Hawaii Department of Education)"_. I'm not convinced this question holds any future value, sorry.

Comment: They are *Internet protocol family* and *internet protocol family 6*, contrary to the assumption of *internet*. As the accepted answer points out, there is even a man page for them. The examples are only understood with a sense of humor. The future value of this ques. may be disputed. But as a reference question, I‘d say the man page link has great value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

inet = Internet protocol family

inet6 = Internet protocol version 6 family

[manpage inet](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/freebsd-manpages/inet.4freebsd.en.html)

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The Internet protocol family is a collection of protocols layered atop the Internet Protocol (IP) transport layer, and utilizing the Internet address format. The Internet family provides protocol support for the SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM, and SOCK_RAW socket types; the SOCK_RAW interface provides access to the IP protocol.

[manpage inet6](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/freebsd-manpages/inet6.4freebsd.en.html#DESCRIPTION)

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The inet6 family is an updated version of inet(4) family. While inet(4) implements Internet Protocol version 4, inet6 implements Internet Protocol version 6.
>
> inet6 is a collection of protocols layered atop the Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6) transport layer, and utilizing the IPv6 address format. The inet6 family provides protocol support for the SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM, and SOCK_RAW socket types; the SOCK_RAW interface provides access to the IPv6 protocol.

Comment: I tried just about every other manual page I could think of, but not `inet` itself!

Answer (score 4):

The `inet` in `ifconfig` output is [an address family](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ifconfig.8.html#Address_Families):

```
If the first argument after the interface name is recognized as the
name of a supported address family, that address family is used for
decoding and displaying all protocol addresses.  Currently supported
address families include inet (TCP/IP, default), inet6 (IPv6), ax25
(AMPR Packet Radio), ddp (Appletalk Phase 2), ipx (Novell IPX) and
netrom (AMPR Packet radio).
```

[`man 7 address_families`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/address_families.7.html) leads to [`man 7 ip`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html), which mentions [`netinet/in.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) (POSIX), which in turn mentions [`arpa/inet.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/arpa_inet.h.html) (POSIX).

And the description of `arpa/inet.h` is:

```
arpa/inet.h - definitions for internet operations
```

So, pretty much, "internet."